# Marcus Jastrow Dictionary Copyright

Tags: books-generally, aramaic, gezel-stealing, intellectual-property, dictionary

Is the dictionary that he wrote still in copyright, or has it entered the public domain? If not, who owns the rights to it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a Torah question but a legal one.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, this is a close one, but given sufficient motivation, it could be on topic. I'm going with leaving open because the most obvious motivation for the question is the desire to publish a new version (electronic or in print), which in the case of this dictionary is Judaism motivated.

Comment: @Yishai The Halachic question is a dup. The legal question is off topic.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, a dupe of what?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, this is not a legal question, best addressed to a lawyer; it's a Jastrow Dictionary question, best addressed to someone who knows about the Jastrow Dictionary. Given that this is a volume used pretty much exclusively in the study of Judaism, it's fair to expect that experts on Judaism would know something about it.

Comment: @Yishai Is there halachic copyright. We have a few of those around

Comment: @IsaacMoses It's a legal question revolving around a Sefer. You can't answer this by knowing the Jastrow. You can by knowing the law. Try replacing Jastrow with another book from 1903 and the answers would be identical.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, replace a ram's head with a boars head and [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45696/how-do-you-prepare-a-rams-head-for-rosh-hashana-night) would be identical. But one is on topic and the other isn't.

Comment: @Yishai http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45696/how-do-you-prepare-a-rams-head-for-rosh-hashana-night#comment121270_45696

Comment: I wouldn't mind if someone were to ask this on Meta

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/whats-the-leading-medical-explanation-for-the-woman-whose-husbands-keep-dying) is featured on [meta](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/178/lists-of-in-and-out-of-scope-topics-for-the-faq/196#196) as an in scope question - and it is about medical science.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe it's been out of copyright for a while. You can access the whole book online here: http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Jastrow/

It's also available on [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=G0ATAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=dictionary+targumim&ei=tOWETLXXEZSIywT7y6ioAw&cd=1#v=onepage&q&f=false), though I only found Vol. 2 there.

[Vol 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/38236) and [Vol 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/38237) are available on Hebrewbooks.org.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. The edition I have (Judaica Press, 1989) carries a copyright of theirs from 1971 (even though the original was published in 1903 and should surely have expired by then).

Comment: It should be that that contents are out of copyright, but the layout(the way the specific pages look) is still under copyright, but the most recent publishers.

Comment: The 1989 (and 1971, I guess) editions are facsimiles of the 1903 one. So there's no new layout to be copyrighted.

Comment: @Alex, Sometimes booksellers/publishers will try to assert copyright when they have none.