# How do you prepare a ram's head for Rosh Hashana night

Tags: minhag, food, cooking-bishul, rosh-hashanah-new-year

One of the Simanim brought to eat on Rosh Hashana is a [Ram's head](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2645). It isn't very popular, I assume due to availability, but one year they had them (well, a lamb's head) in the local store, but I was unable to find any way to prepare it in a way that would be edible.

How do you cook a ram's head for eating on Rosh Hashana night?

Comment: Do gummy animals count?

Comment: I've always felt bad eating the siman of greatness, the head (of a fish in my case) basically while holding my breath out of disgust. I also am never sure what qualifies as 'head'. The gills? Anything past the gills?

Comment: @user6591 "*It is our custom to eat the simanim.  Nevertheless, there are situations when one may merely ‘gaze’ at the items.  For instance, the Kaf HaChaim writes that if one is concerned about insect infestation in one of the simanim, or if one does not enjoy eating a particular siman, he may fulfill the custom by placing the item on the table and looking at it.*" http://www.star-k.com/kashrus/kk-Starting-the-New-Year.htm

Comment: @Shokhet Thanks. I'm aware of that. Its based on two girsaos in the gemara. Its not nauseating, just you know. Not what a siman should be I guess.

Comment: Are you looking for Jewish traditions for cooking it specifically for Rosh Hashana, or generally how to cook head so it is edible? (If the former doesn't exist then you may have better luck asking on [Cooking.se].)

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_cheese) looks like a good option.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I figure someone around here may have successfully eaten it once. I guess we can call that a Jewish tradition of cooking it ;-). Anyway, traditional or not, whatever people come up with. If I don't get anything here, I may ask there. (Seems harder to specify only Kosher ingredients there).

Comment: @Yishai 1 You can specify [kosher](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kosher) there. 2 and more importantly: if you say recipes without any dairy you should be able to adapt it easily enough.

Comment: I'm under the impression that you can buy them pre-cooked in a well-stocked kosher supermarket -- it's probably worthwhile to ask.

Comment: relevant http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44086/759

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about cooking.

Comment: @shmuel, i think you have a misunderstanding about scope. Is a question about making lights for a sukkah off topic because it is about lighting?

Comment: @Yishai If it's the electrical component, then imho yes

Comment: @shmuel, i'm on my mobile, but counter examples abound.

Comment: Yisha @ShmuelBrin That q is at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19096/759 (but note discussion at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31202/759)

Comment: "Not what a siman should be I guess". I can't completely disagree. But, many Jews have been eating pickled and calf's tongue for many years. I guess when it's sliced no one pays much attention to what it is. Maybe, when you serve the head to your guests and yourself, just put small pieces on the plate. I can't quite imagine saying "Yehi Ratzon" with "Baba Black Sheep" staring at you. Besides, what would you do eating all that wool, anyway?

Answer (score 9):

From my experience as a kosher Chef. This is quite an endeavour but not impossible. One lambs head will not provide much meat but enough for all to taste. Here is one with usage of Moroccan spices/ Sephardic flavours which go nicely with lamb and garnished with glazed apples appropriate for the holiday.
For the head;
1 whole lambs head brain removed.( note you may not need salt due to the salting of the meat when Kashered)
2 Tablespoons olive oil
2 large brown sweet onions such as vidalia cut into  8 wedges each
6 cloves garlic sliced 
6 sprigs of fresh thyme
4 cups chicken stock
3 bay leaves
8 black peppercorns
4 pieces of whole clove
1 stick of cinnamon
1 tablespoon of coriander seed
1/2 cup of red wine vinegar

Set oven at 350 degrees F. Rinse head well under cold water. in a roasting pan set on top of the stove heat the oil, cook the onions  until they begin to turn an amber brown. Turn off the heat and add the garlic, thyme, chicken stock, bay, clove, cinnamon,coriander seed, peppercorns and vinegar.Place the head on to the onions. cover with parchment paper and a tight fitting lid or aluminium foil securely so not to lose the liquid inside pan. Cook for 2.5 hours until cheek meat is fork tender.

For the glazed apples; 
4 Granny smith green apples peeled, cored and cut into quarters
2 tablespoons demarara sugar or light brown sugar
1 tablespoon oilve oil
4 cardamom pods crushed
1 tablespoon coriander seed roughly crushed
1 star anise piece crushed
1 dried red chill such as chill di arbol crushed
1/2 cup of strained cooking liquid from the head
1/2 cup honey

Toss apple in the brown sugar to coat. In a saute pan heat oil and carefully add apples in a single layer. lightly caramelize on all sides and place in the 350 degree oven  for approximately 15 minutes until  apples can be pierced easily with a knife.When ready removed apples from pan and set aside. place pan back onto stove and over a medium flame. Add the crushed spices cook for a minute or two  to release their flavours. then add strained cooking broth and honey  Bring to a boil and lower to simmer for ten minutes or until the glaze has thickened. Remove from heat and strain over roasted apples to coat. Taste and adjust with salt black pepper and vinegar if needed.  Place head onto a platter of watercress or arugula ( optional) and pour apples and glaze over the head.

Chag Sameach

Comment: This recipe sounds a bit work-intensive, but I love the spice assortment here. I may try this idea on meat or lamb shanks.